# Android Simple Inflate Fix

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to get my Android application up and running from a ListFragment, but I have a InflatException being thrown. My XML is below and the problem is creating the Fragment, but I'm not sure what the issue is.  I'm trying to convert this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/ to use Fragments and there's a comment down below the tutorial that suggests how to do that briefly.  I'm not sure why there's an error because everything seems correct.  Please let me know if you need more information from me and I'll be happy to help.

Android:

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        ...
```

XML:

```
<relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk..."
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/too..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <listview
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerheight="1dp"
        android:listselector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</relativelayout>
```

Logcat:

```
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167): Process: com.rynovation.kline, PID: 9167
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class relativelayout
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at com.rynovation.kline.mainViewController2.onCreateView(mainViewController2.java:40)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1453)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.relativelayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.rynovation.kline-176.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.rynovation.kline-176, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
09-08 18:45:25.572: E/AndroidRuntime(9167):     ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<RelativeLayout ... />` with a `R`